# How to load images from Google Cloud Storage with keras.preprocessing

Tags: keras, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-ml

I am writing machine learning code that can be trained locally or in the cloud.  I am using keras.preprocessing to load images, which under the hood uses PIL.  It works fine for local files, but understandably doesn't understand Google Cloud Storage paths, like "gs://...".

`from keras.preprocessing import image
image.load_img("gs://myapp-some-bucket/123.png")`

Gives this error:

`.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/preprocessing/image.py", line 320, in load_img img = pil_image.open(path) File 
.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2530, in open fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb") IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs://myapp-some-bucket/123.png'`

What is the correct way of doing this?  I ultimately need a folder of images to be a single numpy array (images decoded and grayscale).

Comment: I'm not familiar with Keras. It might not support direct GCS access. If the data set is not large, you can copy the data set to the VM first by using the preinstalled gsutil cli. In python, you can call os.system('gsutil cp YOUR_GCS_FILE .')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a replacement for keras.preprocessing.image.load_img, that understands GCS.  I also included more code to read the whole folder, and turn every image in the folder into a single numpy array for training...

```
import os
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import gfile
filelist = gfile.ListDirectory("gs://myapp-some-bucket")
sess = tf.Session()
with sess.as_default():
   x = np.array([np.array(tf.image.decode_png(tf.read_file(os.path.join(train_files_dir, filename))).eval()) for filename in filelist])
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. However for some reason "gfile.ListDirectory" isnt finding my directory. I get back a could not find directory error.

Answer (score 0):

Load image:

```
image_path = 'gs://xxxxxxx.jpg'
image = tf.read_file(image_path)
image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image)
image_array = sess.run(image)
```

Save image:

```
job_dir = 'gs://xxxxxxxx'
image = tf.image.encode_jpeg(image_array)
file_name = 'xxx.jpg'
write_op = tf.write_file(os.path.join(job_dir, file_name), image)
sess.run(write_op)
```